# Counting Frequency of Strings in 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am somewhat stuck on a piece of code that I'm hoping I can get some insight on here.

Essentially I am reading an input file, grabbing the bit values and storing them. in a 2D array.

What I'm trying to accomplish is finding the number of occurrences of each string in the 2D array.

For example, Here is what is being stored in the 1st couple of entries in the 2d array `sortBuffer[][]`

```
111000101
110000101
111110000
101011000
000000010
101001000
```

So what I need to accomplish, is creating a count array that will tell me the number of times, say `111000101`, or `110000101` occurs within the `sortBuffer`.

Since it's a 2D array I'm working with, I'm not really sure how to compare the entire string. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

As an additional step, I need to organize the array by bit values, starting with

```
000000001
000000010
000000011
000000100  and so on...
```

---

```
int getBitVal(unsigned char *keyStrBin, int keyIndex) {

    int keyMod = keyIndex % 8;  
    int keyIn = keyIndex / 8;

    return (((keyStrBin[keyIn]) >> (7 - (keyMod))) & 1);
}

void test(FILE *inputFile) {
    int nRead;
    size_t fSize = size(inputFile);
    unsigned char *inBuffer = malloc(fSize * sizeof (unsigned char));
    memset(inBuffer, 0, fSize);

    nRead = fread(inBuffer, 1, fSize, inputFile);

    int h = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int m = 9
    int n = 24720
    char sortBuffer[m][n / m];

    for (i = 0; i < fSize * 8; i++) {
        sortBuffer[b][h] = getBitVal(inBuffer, i);
        b++;
        if (i % m == 0 && i != 0) {
            b = 0;
            h++;
        }  
    }

//This is where I need to count the number of times any given string occurs within the `sortBuffer` `char`.
```

Comment: `sizeof (unsigned char)` is useless, as it is defined to yield `1`.

Comment: How would I convert the strings to int? At least getting all the say 9 values within the string into a single int valu?

Comment: Right, sizeof (unsigned char), I typically just add it there for reference later on.

Comment: You can treat "000000010" as the binary representation of the integer "2". Then use a frequency map (int array[512] as you have 9 binary digits) to count how many times "2" appears.

Comment: 111000101
That makes sense. So since sortBuffer[0][0] = 1, sortBuffer[1][0] = 1, sortBuffer[2][0] = 1. sortBuffer[3][0] = 0, and so on. How would I make a single string of the value instead of individual int values?

Comment: what if the incoming data is 0?   To allow for a 9 bit pattern, declare: `size_t freqArray[512];`   then when each bit pattern is read, then `freqArray[bitPattern]++;`  to print each bit pattern use: `for( size_t i=0; i< 512; i++ ) { printf( pattern: %5x occurred %ul times\n", i, freqArray[i] ); }`

Comment: I adopted something like this, but I had to account for there not being exactly 512 matches as to not get invalid frequency results during printout. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of calculating the frequency and sorting the data where the width to be 9 and the data is already in the array instead of being read from a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int height=6;
  int sortBuffer[6][9] = {
   {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
   {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
   {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
   {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
   {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}
  };
  int freq[2<<9]={0};
  int print, count, index, row, column, value;
  // store the counts
  for(row=0;row<height;row++)
  {
    for(value=0,column=0;column<9;column++) value=value*2+sortBuffer[row][column];
    freq[value]++;
  }
  // print the numbers
  for(index=0;index<(2<<9);index++)
  {
    for(count=freq[index];count>0;count--)
    {
      for(print=9;print>0;print--) printf("%d", (index & (1<<(print-1))) >> (print-1) );
      puts("");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the first for loop we calculate a decimal number for all the bits.  We start with a value 0 and then for each bit in the number we shift the value one bit left and add the current bit. At the end of the loop all the bits have been shifted in and we have an integer that contains all the bits.  We use that as an index into the freqency array and increment the value at that index - that value is the count of the number of times that the value exists.

In the second for loop we run through the frequency array and for each value print out however copies of the number we need.  Since we start at index 0 we are automatically printing them in sorted order.  The tricky part is printing one bit from an integer - basically you need to mask the bit you want with & and then shift it down to the ones place.  For example, to get the fourth bit of V you need to `(V & (1 << 3)) >> 3` which is the same as `(V & (1 << (4-1))) >> (4-1)`  and in our case `index` is the value and `print` is the bit.